# Pendivre USB OTG on Nexus4?

Tags: nexus-4, insufficient-memory, usb-on-the-go

Does Nexus4 supports a use a USB pendrive (up to 64Gb)?

If yes, with the USB OTG is I can navigate in the folders of the pendrive from the smartphone?

Is it possible to copy file from pendrive to N4 and from N4 to pendrive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nexus 4 does not officially support USB OTG. But rooting and modding the software can do the trick. Here's a [handy guide](http://m.androidcentral.com/android-advanced-usb-otg-nexus-4) I found!

Answer (score 1):

The Nexus 4 doesn't officialy support USB OTG. It is possible with a custom kernel. But for this you need to unlock your bootloader.